# Getting unexpected result while using CountVectorizer()

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, text-mining

I am trying to use `CountVectorizer()` in a loop, But I am getting an unexpected result. On the other hand, if I use it outside the loop then it works fine. I believe there is some small problem with the logic.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

keys_1 = ['funny', 'amusing', 'humorous', 'hilarious', 'jolly']
keys_2 = ['horror', 'fear', 'shock', 'panic', 'scream']
keys_3 = ['romantic', 'intimate', 'passionate', 'love', 'fond']

text = ('funny amusing fear passionate')

for i in range(3):
    keys = 'keys_' + str(i+1)
    cv = CountVectorizer(vocabulary = keys) 
    data = cv.fit_transform([text]).toarray()
    print(data)

cv1 = CountVectorizer(vocabulary = keys_1) 
data = cv1.fit_transform([text]).toarray()
print(data)

cv2 = CountVectorizer(vocabulary = keys_2) 
data = cv2.fit_transform([text]).toarray()
print(data)

cv3 = CountVectorizer(vocabulary = keys_3) 
data = cv3.fit_transform([text]).toarray()
print(data)
```

Output

> [[0 0 0 0 0 0]]
>
> [[0 0 0 0 0 0]]
>
> [[0 0 0 0 0 0]]
>
> [[1 1 0 0 0]]
>
> [[0 1 0 0 0]]
>
> [[0 0 1 0 0]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the line:

```
keys = 'keys_' + str(i+1)
```

Here, keys becomes a string variable while I guess you would expect it to take the value of the list you defined in the first lines..

Try instead with a dictionary:

```
my_keys= {
"keys_1" : ['funny', 'amusing', 'humorous', 'hilarious', 'jolly'],
"keys_2" : ['horror', 'fear', 'shock', 'panic', 'scream'],
"keys_3" : ['romantic', 'intimate', 'passionate', 'love', 'fond']
}
text = ('funny amusing fear passionate')

for i in range(3):
    keys = my_keys['keys_' + str(i+1)]
    cv = CountVectorizer(vocabulary = keys) 
    data = cv.fit_transform([text]).toarray()
    print(data)
```